# jQuery - Click to Hide Target and Other DIVs, and Scroll to Target DIV

Tags: jquery

I did my homework on this one, and found solutions for different parts, but surprisingly did not find the answer to the overall solution. The desired behavior:

I've got four images, each with it's own hidden div section. Clicking on the trigger image closes the other divs, opens the target div, then scrolls to that div. If the target div is open, clicking on the trigger image closes its target div (this is where I have failed).

Thanks to my hours of reading here, and many trials and tribulations, while it may not be the cleanest or most efficient code block, I've got all behavior except the self-closing (I can close other divs and scroll to the target however, I can't close the target div when I click on its trigger).

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Show / Hide & Scroll to Multiple DIVs</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#div_1").slideUp('fast');
    $("#div_2").slideUp('fast');
    $("#div_3").slideUp('fast');
    $("#div_4").slideUp('fast');

    $("#show_trigger_1").click(function () {
      if ($("#div_1").is(':hidden')) {      
        $("#div_2").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_3").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_4").slideUp('fast');
        $("body,html").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#div_1").offset().top
        }, 100);
        $("#div_1").slideToggle('fast');
      }
    });

    $("#show_trigger_2").click(function () {
      var wasVisible = $("#div_2").is(':visible');
      $('[id^=element]:visible').stop().slideUp('fast');
      if (!wasVisible) { 
        $("#div_1").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_3").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_4").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_2").slideDown('fast');
          $("body,html").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#div_2").offset().top
          }, 200);
      }
    });

    $("#show_trigger_3").click(function () {
    if ($("#div_3").is(':hidden')) {      
      $("#div_1").slideUp('fast');
      $("#div_2").slideUp('fast');
      $("#div_4").slideUp('fast');
      $("#div_3").slideDown('fast');
    }
      $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div_3").offset().top
      }, 400);
    });

    $("#show_trigger_4").click(function () {
    if ($("#div_4").is(':hidden')) {      
        $("#div_1").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_2").slideUp('fast');
        $("#div_3").slideUp('fast');
      $("#div_4").slideDown('fast');
    }
      $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div_4").offset().top
      }, 600);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#containers-wrap {
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#containers-wrap div {
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav"> <a id="show_trigger_1"><img src="http://placehold.it/125&text=Image+1"></a> <a id="show_trigger_2"><img src="http://placehold.it/125&text=Image+2"></a> <a id="show_trigger_3"><img src="http://placehold.it/125&text=Image+3"></a> <a id="show_trigger_4"><img src="http://placehold.it/125&text=Image+4"></a> </div>

<div id="containers-wrap">
  <div id="div_1"> Content of Div 1 Here </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="div_2"> Content of Div 2 Here </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="div_3"> Content of Div 3 Here </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="div_4"> Content of Div 4 Here </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your input is immensely appreciated!

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/KillerDesigner/1uybywum/6/

EDIT: I forgot to mention that each of the four jquery sections are my attempt to make the desired behavior work. Feel free to condemn me - I'm a NOOB.

```
onclick
create var with class and id (a.class#id)
split id at div_ so that I can target numbered ids
if class.id of clicked element is open
  set its class to close
  then close all elements with close classes
    if class.id of clicked element is close
      set its class to open
      open class.div_
      scroll to it
end
```

Comment: don't have time to give full response, but I think you want to rethink your approach a little. On click, you should set a class on the cliked element, perhaps ".active". Then if you click elsewhere, clear all ".active"s and hide them. You also shouldn't have these explicit "when I click on "1", hide "2", "3", "4", etc -- it should be generic so that all ".item" divs (or likewise) get effected. Sorry of if this is a little rambling, but you should only have a couple of methods there.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I see where you're going with this, leading me into a new direction. I'll circle back here to report progress.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks again. I refactored the code as suggested. While it is certainly cleaner, I still can't get the second click on the same image to close it's target div. http://jsfiddle.net/KillerDesigner/1uybywum/8/

Comment: With the scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/KillerDesigner/1uybywum/9/

Comment: So,Jonathan, based on your input, I arrived at, but am struggling with, a new of doing this (see the main edit above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something along these lines should help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav a").click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split('_');
    $("#divs_container div").removeClass("active");
    $("#divs_container #div_"+id[1]).addClass("active");
    $("#divs_container div:not(.active)").slideUp();
    $("#divs_container div.active").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ppna9b2/

a little more with the slide to functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav a").click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split('_');
    $("#divs_container div").removeClass("active");
    $("#divs_container #div_"+id[1]).addClass("active");
    $("#divs_container div:not(.active)").slideUp();
    // if it's already open:
    // remove class and close it
    if($("#divs_container #div_"+id[1]).hasClass("open")){
       $("#divs_container #div_"+id[1]).removeClass("open").slideUp();
    }
   // if it's not open:
   // close any open ones
   // remove the .open class
   // add .open class to target, open it, and scroll to
   else{
       $("#divs_container .open").slideUp().removeClass("open");
       $("#divs_container #div_"+id[1]).addClass("open").slideDown();
       $('body,html #divs_container #div_"+id[1]').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#div_"+id[1]).offset().top
       }, 800);
   }
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zss9nzgz/

Comment: Wow! Sweet! I was pretty close. I had the logic, but couldn't figure out how write the code to execute the logic. Thank you Jonathan.

Comment: Thank you! I don't want to wear out my wecome, but.. I wanted it to scroll when active, so I added this: http://jsfiddle.net/KillerDesigner/u5xnc7fL/5/ however, it scrolls both when active, and when :not. I tried an if condition, just not understanding the logic: http://jsfiddle.net/2ppna9b2/. Might you offer one more insight, and let me put this to bed? That's four days I'll never get back! lol ;)

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. http://jsfiddle.net/KillerDesigner/u5xnc7fL/6/ Thanks again for your guidance and assistance!